# Dependeny Injection Error Unable to resolve service for type while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm getting Dependency Injection Eror when I try POST data via Postman.

This is code in controller and service file.

**DashboardController.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/dashboards")]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IDashboardService dashboardService;

        public DashboardController(IDashboardService dashboardService)
        {
            this.dashboardService = dashboardService;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Describe this method here.
        /// </summary>
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateDashboard([FromBody]Dashboard dashboardResource)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    return BadRequest(ModelState);

                var createdDashboard = await dashboardService.Create(dashboardResource);
                return Ok(createdDashboard);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DashboardService.cs**

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Domain.Services
{
    public class DashboardService: IDashboardService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<Dashboard> dashboardRepository;

        public DashboardService(IRepository<Dashboard> dashboardRepository)
        {
            this.dashboardRepository = dashboardRepository;
        }

        public async Task<Dashboard> Create(Dashboard dashboard)
        {
            var createdDashboard = await dashboardRepository.Create(dashboard);
            return createdDashboard;
        }
    }
}
```

In Startup method ConfigureServices I've addded AddScoped

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddAutoMapper();

                services.AddScoped<IDashboardService, DashboardService>();
                services.AddScoped<IRepository<Dashboard>, DashboardRepository>();

                services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

                services.AddMvc();

                services.AddTransient<DatabaseDeployer>();
            }
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong. I use N-tier arhitecture with repository, automapper etc..

**DashboardRepository.cs**

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace Repositories.Repositories
{
    public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<domain.Dashboard>
    {
        private readonly DbContext context;
        private readonly IMapper mapper;

        public DashboardRepository(DbContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<domain.Dashboard> Create(domain.Dashboard dashboard)
        {
            var entityToCreate = mapper.Map<domain.Dashboard, dbModels.Dashboard>(dashboard);

            var createdEntity = context.Add(entityToCreate);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            var createDashboard = mapper.Map<dbModels.Dashboard, domain.Dashboard>(dashboard); 
        }
```

Comment: What does `DashboardRepository` look like?

Comment: make sure `Dashboard` is `Sticos.Personal.Domain.Entities.Dashboard` and not other class with same name.

Comment: @maccettura I've added repository class.

Comment: I think @tchelidze has the right idea.  Hover over the interface implementation of your DashboardRepository class and see what the namespace of `Dashboard` is.  Then make sure it matches the `Dashboard` in your Startup.cs

Comment: @tchelidze I was thinking about it. Use the same name for dashobard class in Domain project Entity folder and Repository Project Models folder., but I can not add reference from Repository.Model in Domain because I have circular dependency error..

Comment: You haven't added `IMapper` as a service.

Comment: @DavidG wouldn't that mean the `IDashboardService` resolution would fail first?  Not the repository

Comment: @enzodev I think you should have **interfaces** of repositories inside domain layer, and implementation in Infrastructure. Domain is not dependent on any other layer.

Comment: @maccettura Not saying it will necessarily solve the problem, just adding more info. Looking at the `DashboardRepository` class though, there are 2 `Dashboard` classes being used in there, pretty sure the wrong one is used.

Comment: @DavidG yeah I definitely agree that its the wrong dashboard being used.  OP should look at my previous comment to see the steps I outlined

Comment: @tchelidze I have interafaces in domain layer. Please look picture of project I've added.

Comment: `public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<Dashboard>` should probably be `public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<domain.Dashboard>`

Comment: In startup `services.AddScoped<IRepository<Sticos.Personal.Domain.Entities.Dashboard.Dashboard>, DashboardRepository>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have referenced incorrect `Dashboard` in `Startup` and `DashboardRepository` class.

*DashboardRepository.cs*

```
public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<Domain.Entities.Dashboard.Dashboard>
```

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<Domain.Entities.Dashboard.Dashboard>, DashboardRepository>();
```

*Note*

Look at `DashboardRepository` class, you have defined

```
using domain = Domain.Entities;
```

but are using `Dashboard` class directly

```
public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<Dashboard>
```

instead of

```
public class DashboardRepository : IRepository<domain.Dashboard>
```

So, `Dashboard` refers to `Repositories.Models.Dashboard`, since you have added following using statement

```
using Repositories.Models;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i forgot to inject dependecny in startup.cs

```
Public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<ISyncRequestRepository, SyncRequestManager>();     
}
```